# What is the correct graph of the difference between two numbers in the real line?

Tags: notation

Leaving aside the sign or direction of something like 5 - 3, which perhaps would need to include an arrowhead, as well as other possible graphical conventions I am not familiar with,

> Which one of the graphical options below (A or B) would make more sense to express 5 - 3:

[image]

> ?

I would say that A makes more sense, because you are "leaving 3 behind" and moving on along the real line until you reach 5. So 5 should be included, but 3 should be excluded.

Comment: Is this standard notation or are you making something up for personal use?

Comment: Personal use. Say, you are explaining a slightly more advanced concept, and resorting to subtraction of real numbers as an analogy. So the graph does not fully encapsulate, but approximates the idea.

Comment: Im not sure if this post will do very well on here — opinion-based questions are not considered good practice, but for what it’s worth I would say that A is a better notation, because as well as the reasons you gave, it also captures the lack of symmetry (commutativity) in the subtraction operation

Comment: @aidangallagher4 It is definitely NOT opinion based. What I meant to say is that, for instance, I don't know if there is a standardized way of drawing it, which would, perhaps include an arrowhead. But the question stands regardless of the drawing.

Comment: Well if you are talking about interval notation (http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/07-solving-inequalities/03-interval-notation-02), and what you are trying to describe is the interval with 5 but not 3 (in the integers), then unambiguously the answer is A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed in the comments (sorry I think I initially misinterpreted what you were trying to say as subtraction not an interval), if you are indeed talking about interval notation (http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/07-solving-inequalities/03-interval-notation-02), then A is the correct answer, as $\circ$ indicates an “open” interval (ie strictly greater or less then). A line indicates a “closed” interval (greater than/less than or equal to).

In non-diagrammatic notation, the interval you’re trying to express would be written is either $(3,5]$ or $]3,5]$, both of which are equivalent ways of saying

$$\{ x \mid 3 < x \leqslant 5, x \in \Bbb{R} \}.$$

Comment: What's the difference between subtraction and interval in terms of the concept of the "space in between or separation from 3 to 5"?

Comment: @Butternut Well in this case not much because we’ve endowed the real numbers with something resembling the euclidian metric (ill admit im a little hazy on metric spaces but read here for more info https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)), but in general it is important to make the distinction.